# Can I connect two computers on an ADSL modem which has one USB port and one Ethernet port?

Tags: networking, router, usb, modem

I have an ADSL2 modem + router. It has one USB connector and one Ethernet port. It is not a wireless router-modem.

Can I use both of my computers on each one to access the internet?

Here [are the specs](http://www.iball.co.in/Product/ADSL2--Router--Ver-3-0-/388) for the modem; ADSL2+ Router (Ver 3.0), Model No: iB-LR6111A.

Comment: That model has one WAN port, one LAN port one USB port. The fact that it has a WAN port means it connects to a modem and is not a modem.  I suggest you correct your title /  change your question

Comment: @barlop - *"it connects to a modem and is not a modem."* -- A device with a RJ11 port and marked as "ADSL" would be a modem.  All of your comments based on your faulty assessment are simply wrong.

Comment: @sawdust ah quite right, I misread. I saw a google result or two that said it provides a WAN port not realizing it meant RJ11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, no. The purpose of a USB port on an ADSL modem like that is to allow you direct connection to a computer alone to allow it to operate as a modem as well as provide a clean connection for firmware updates only.

The Ethernet port would basically be the same, but just with Ethernet & with the benefit of the DHCP router. If you want more than one device to be connected to the modem you need to hook it up to an Ethernet hub or switch.

Comment: *"The purpose of a USB port on an ADSL modem like that is to allow you direct connection to a computer alone to allow it to operate as a modem as well as provide a clean connection for firmware updates only."* -- Not necessarily.  I had a Westell ADSL modem+router that also had both USB and RJ45 ports.  Either could be used for an Ethernet connection to a PC.  The PC saw the USB connection as a USB-to-Ethernet adapter connected to the modem+router.